# How do I get the source for a Python class I declared programmatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reflection, metaprogramming, metaclass

I'm trying to use `inspect.getsource()` to get the source of a class that was defined like this:

```
import inspect

Cat = type('Cat', (), {})

def meow_local(self):
  print("meow")

Cat.meow = meow_local

print(inspect.getsource(Cat))
```

The error I get from inspect is:

> OSError: could not find class definition

It is understandable that inspect does not know the correct place to find the Cat class. Where should I tell inspect to look?

Or is there another way to get the same results?

Comment: Not sure, but I think the second parameter to type should be   (object,)

Comment: make sure you saved the file as a python file too. Doesn't solve it, but helps.

Comment: @stefan type() with 3 params returns a new type and expects 1. Name 2. Tuple of base classes 3. Dict of attribs

Answer (score 0):

You don't.
And you can't, as there is no source code for it.

`inspect.getsource` works by finding out the actuall `.py` file something is
defined in, and getting the file lines, as they are on disk, with comments, whitespace, and such.

Even if you fill up all meta-information needed on a programatically defined class to the point you will get a  `__file__` value, and line information in the code objects, `getsource` will jsut try to read that file and get the text in there.

You don't mention anything about your actual problem - if you want to have Python code for your created classes, you can invert the thing, and introspect yur generated classes to *write* a  proper `.py` file that does the same as the programatic call did in first place.

On the other hand, if you want the source code for the lines containing the `type` call, that is feasible - but you will have to customize the class creation to the point of having the file and line number information on the code object used to create the class. Calling `type` does not use a code object to startwith - but there are ways to do it, although complicated. A while back I answered a question about if it was possible to make a programatically declared class to be indistinguishable from a normal, declared class - and I dig real deep into it -  that answer will show all the meta-attributes that are used in the normal way, some of which you'd have to fill in - or worse - *forge* to create a programatic class which creation call can be pinpointed by `getsource`:

[Detect if class was defined declarative or functional - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158324/detect-if-class-was-defined-declarative-or-functional-possible/53190098#53190098)

Comment: I have a large number of text files that describe class names and attributes. I want to generate the class definition boilerplate, setters/getters and put them into files. From there they can be edited. I know I can use templating like jinjia2 and caveman this. I just want to see if I could find a more clever way; maybe not.

Comment: So you really want to render readable Python for the class specs you have laying in text files. I think jinja2 or other templating,combined with introspection, if you want to create the actuall class objects, can work nicely.